# Jsonpath Sort array

Tags: sorting, soapui, jsonpath

Please could you help me sort array which I get using $..balanceChange. It is a small part of response.

I need it for assertion in SoapUI.

```
 {
      "id": 182,
      "name": "49899 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern",
      "eventDefinition":       {
         "id": 111,
         "name": "49899 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern",
         "shortName": null,
         "displayName": "49899 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern",
         "active": true,
         "group": null,
         "lowerThresholdAmount": 0,
         "upperThresholdAmount": 0,
         "lowerThresholdDayAmount": null,
         "upperThresholdDayAmount": null,
         "amountUnit": null,
         "exceptionType": null,
         "comment": null,
         "paycode": null,
         "paycodeAmountType": null,
         "usedType": null,
         "punchType": null,
         "type": {"name": "pattern"},
         "extendedData": null,
         "dayBased": false
      },
      "policyDefinition":       {
         "id": 404,
         "name": "49899 Consolidated Sick w S&S plc467381724319"
      },
      "ruleDefinition":       {
         "id": 604,
         "name": "WR467381724319"
      },
      "pointTransaction":       {
         "id": 313,
         "name": "Attendance Points 1",
         "employeeId": 385,
         "balanceChange": 5,
         "typeCategory": "POINT",
         "applyDate": "2016-04-28T00:00:00"
      },
      "type": {"name": "pattern"},
      "employeeId": 385,
      "applyDate": "2016-04-28",
      "eventTime": "00:00:00",
      "amount": null,
      "dayAmount": null,
      "updatedByUserId": 12,
      "isSystem": true
   }
```

Comment: How do you want to sort it (Id, name or by object)? Could you give more explanation?

Comment: When it $..balanceChange  execute, I have got [9.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 6.0, 5.0]. But sometimes this sequence is change and I can get [8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 6.0, 5.0]. I need to sort this array by balanceChange

Comment: So, the simple way is use underscore. See answer may be it can help you, if not I will try to rewrite the code, just let me know

Comment: the example you have shown does not contains any of the values like 9.0, 8.0 etc.

Answer (score -5):

Try to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) lib. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HAqHCp9bRwgWhpENsgYc?p=preview)

```
   var arr  = [
  { 
  "id": 182,
  "name": "49899 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern"
},
{ 
  "id": 183,
  "name": "49900 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern"
},{ 
  "id": 184,
  "name": "49901 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern"
},{ 
  "id": 185,
  "name": "49902 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern"
},{ 
  "id": 186,
  "name": "49903 Consol Sick w S&S Pattern"
},]


console.log(_.sortBy(arr, 'id'))
```

or just simplest (example in plunker)

```
var data = [9.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 6.0, 5.0]
console.log(data.sort());
```

Comment: OP specified he is using SoapUI, which does not have a JS interpreter.

Comment: This answer sadly does not respect the boudary give by the question